# Create a lambda expression containing a new expression with an anonymous type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

How to build a lambda expression for an Entity Framework query dynamically (e.g. at API level) that contains a NEW expression with an anonymous type. The members of the anonymous type (Item0, Item1, ...) are only known at runtime?
An example:

```
Orders
.GroupBy(param0 => param0.Products)
.Select(param0 => new
    {
        Item0 = param0.Where(param1 => param1.Id == 10).Select(param1 => param1.Value),
        Item1 = param0.Where(param1 => param1.Id == 11).Select(param1 => param1.Description)
    }
)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? A user-driven query?

Comment: Exactly, the idea is to build a user-driven EntityFramework query.